# is it possible to point admin-on-rest at multiple endpoints?

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

examples show a single endpoint, for example:

```
render(
    <Admin restClient={simpleRestClient('http://localhost:3000')}>
        <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} edit={PostEdit} create={PostCreate} icon={PostIcon}/>
    </Admin>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

is there a strategy for presenting restful resources spanning multiple "root" endpoints, like:

- http://host-1
- http://host-2

in a single admin-on-rest instance?

i guess it would need to look something like:

```
render(
    <Admin>
        <Resource name="widgets" list={WidgetList} restClient={restClientOne('http://host-1')/>
        <Resource name="whatsits" list={WhatsitList} restClient={restClientTwo('http://host-2')/>
    </Admin>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this at the resource level by using the package that @gildas has mentioned in the comments.

You can write your own REST client that looks at the resource being called and accesses different APIs.

Link below should provide some insight into how the REST client works. Though this is an example of a rest client wrapper.

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#decorating-your-rest-client-example-of-file-upload

What your REST Client needs to do is.

const RESTclient = requestHandler => (type, resource, params) => {

```
if (resource == 'Resource1') {
    const url = API1 + .....
} else if (resource == 'Resource2)
    const url = API2 + .....
}
```

You can go through the code for any of the community Rest clients to see how they all make their requests. Above link was the best resource in aor docs for me.

Comment: You can find some more infos in this [issue](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/682). Take away: use this addon: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aor-rest-client-router

Comment: @Gildas this looks like a really cool package I could have totally used 2 months ago :)